# How to join a table twice

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following two tables and I would like to join them to make a third table

Table A

```
customer_id first_order_date last_order_date
123          2017-04-06        2018-07-30
456          2017-08-07        2018-07-24
789          2018-03-13        2018-07-03
```

Table B

```
order_id customer_id order_created_at num_of_products num_of_x_products
abc       123         2017-04-06           4              2
xyz       123         2018-07-30           5              3
def       456         2017-08-07           6              6
lmn       456         2018-07-24           4              1
ghi       789         2018-03-13           6              5
pqr       789         2018-07-03           3              3
```

I want to join these two tables and create a third one that looks like. How do I do that?

```
customer_id first_order_date last_order_date first_num_of_products last_num_of_products
123           2017-04-06        2018-07-30        4         5
456           2017-08-07        2018-07-24        6         4
```

Here's my code

```
 SELECT
          "cus".customer_id
          ,"fo".order_created_at as first_order_created_at
          ,"fo".order_id as first_order_id
          ,"fo".number_of_products as first_number_of_products   
          ,"lo".order_created_at as last_order_created_at
          ,"lo".order_id as last_order_id
          ,"lo".number_of_products as last_number_of_products

        FROM table_a AS "cus"
        INNER JOIN table_b AS "fo" 
        ON "cus".customer_id = "fo".customer_id
        AND "cus".first_order_date = "fo".order_created_at
        INNER JOIN table_b AS "lo" 
        ON "cus".customer_id = "lo".customer_id
        AND "cus".last_order_date = "lo".order_created_at
```

Comment: Have you researched joins and attempted to write one?

Comment: @dfundako I have and it seems like I have to join the first table to the second table twice but I'm not getting any results for some reason. Would love some help!

Comment: Share the code you wrote.

Comment: From your sample data and expect ,I think you don't need to use `JOIN` you can only write a query.

Comment: @dfundako question has been included to include the code

Comment: @D-Shih snowflake

Comment: Please explain properly what problem you are facing

Comment: You want to create a third table and insert record in that table using these two tables right?

Answer (score 0):

From your sample data and expected result, I think you don't need to use `JOIN` you can only write a query like this.

Although this example is SQL-server, `snowflake` supports the `row_number`function and the *window function*.

`JOIN` tabelA and tableB in subquery by `t1.order_created_at = t2.first_order_date` or `t1.order_created_at = t2.last_order_date` and `t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id`

the result will only get `first_order_date` and `last_order_date` so use `Row_number` make the rownumber by `order_created_at`.

1. `rn=1` mean `first_order_date`
2. `rn=2` mean `last_order_date`

use *condition aggregate function*.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(
  customer_id INT,
  first_order_date DATE,
  last_order_date DATE
);


insert into TableA values (123,'2017-04-06','2018-07-30');
insert into TableA values (456,'2017-08-07','2018-07-24');
insert into TableA values (789,'2018-03-13','2018-07-03');


CREATE TABLE TableB(
  customer_id INT,
  order_created_at DATE,
  num_of_products INT,
  num_of_x_products INT
);


INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ( 123,'2017-04-06',4,2);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ( 123,'2018-07-28',15,13);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ( 123,'2018-07-30',5,3);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ( 456,'2017-08-07',6,6);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ( 456,'2018-07-24',4,1);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ( 789,'2018-03-13',6,5);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ( 789,'2018-07-03',3,3);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       MIN(order_created_at) first_order_date,
       MAX(order_created_at) last_order_date, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN num_of_products END) first_num_of_products,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN num_of_products END) last_num_of_products
FROM 
(
  select t1.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.customer_id ORDER BY t1.order_created_at) rn
  from TableB t1 
  INNER JOIN TableA t2 ON 
  (t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id) AND
  (t1.order_created_at = t2.first_order_date OR t1.order_created_at = t2.last_order_date)

) t1
WHERE t1.customer_id in (123,456)
GROUP BY t1.customer_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/07de8/2/0)**:

```
| customer_id | first_order_date | last_order_date | first_num_of_products | last_num_of_products |
|-------------|------------------|-----------------|-----------------------|----------------------|
|         123 |       2017-04-06 |      2018-07-30 |                     4 |                    5 |
|         456 |       2017-08-07 |      2018-07-24 |                     6 |                    4 |
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but most customers have more than two orders. That was just an example. I'm pretty sure I'm going to have to use a join

Comment: @PreetRajdeo From your comment, I edit my answer you can try it  write a subquery to `JOIN` the `first_order_date ` or `last_order_date`, if `rn=1` then first `rn=2` mean last.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with JOIN very simply.

```
WITH tablea(customer_id,first_order_date, last_order_date) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
    (123, '2017-04-06','2018-07-30'),
    (456, '2017-08-07','2018-07-24'),
    (789, '2018-03-13','2018-07-03')
), tableb(order_id, customer_id, order_created_at, num_of_products, num_of_x_products) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('abc',123,'2017-04-06',4,2),
    ('xyz',123,'2018-07-30',5,3),
    ('def',456,'2017-08-07',6,6),
    ('lmn',456,'2018-07-24',4,1),
    ('ghi',789,'2018-03-13',6,5),
    ('pqr',789,'2018-07-03',3,3)
)
SELECT a.customer_id
    ,a.first_order_date
    ,a.last_order_date
    ,fb.num_of_products
    ,lb.num_of_products
FROM tablea AS a
JOIN tableb AS fb
    ON a.customer_id = fb.customer_id AND a.first_order_date = fb.order_created_at
JOIN tableb AS lb
    ON a.customer_id = lb.customer_id AND a.last_order_date = lb.order_created_at
;
```

Gives:

| CUSTOMER_ID | FIRST_ORDER_DATE | LAST_ORDER_DATE | NUM_OF_PRODUCTS | NUM_OF_PRODUCTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2017-04-06 | 2018-07-30 | 4 | 5 |
| 456 | 2017-08-07 | 2018-07-24 | 6 | 4 |
| 789 | 2018-03-13 | 2018-07-03 | 6 | 3 |

What has not been described, is why you didn't ask for `789`

It can also be done via a DISTINCT clause and FIRST_VALUE/LAST_VALUE just from tableb

```
WITH tableb(order_id, customer_id, order_created_at, num_of_products, num_of_x_products) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('abc',123,'2017-04-06',4,2),
    ('xyz',123,'2018-07-30',5,3),
    ('def',456,'2017-08-07',6,6),
    ('lmn',456,'2018-07-24',4,1),
    ('ghi',789,'2018-03-13',6,5),
    ('pqr',789,'2018-07-03',3,3)
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    customer_id
    ,first_value(order_created_at) over (partition by customer_id order by order_created_at) as first_order_date
    ,last_value(order_created_at) over (partition by customer_id order by order_created_at) as last_order_date
    ,first_value(num_of_products) over (partition by customer_id order by order_created_at) as first_order_date
    ,last_value(num_of_products) over (partition by customer_id order by order_created_at) as last_order_date
FROM tableb;
```

gives:

| CUSTOMER_ID | FIRST_ORDER_DATE | LAST_ORDER_DATE | FIRST_ORDER_DATE | LAST_ORDER_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2017-04-06 | 2018-07-30 | 4 | 5 |
| 456 | 2017-08-07 | 2018-07-24 | 6 | 4 |
| 789 | 2018-03-13 | 2018-07-03 | 6 | 3 |

Lastly we can drop the grouping option of distinct and use QUALIFY to drop "some rows we don't want" which we will do via a ROW_NUMBER and an ORDER BY TRUE because we really don't care:

```
WITH tableb(order_id, customer_id, order_created_at, num_of_products, num_of_x_products) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('abc',123,'2017-04-06',4,2),
    ('xyz',123,'2018-07-30',5,3),
    ('def',456,'2017-08-07',6,6),
    ('lmn',456,'2018-07-24',4,1),
    ('ghi',789,'2018-03-13',6,5),
    ('pqr',789,'2018-07-03',3,3)
)
SELECT 
    customer_id
    ,first_value(order_created_at) over (order by order_created_at) as first_order_date
    ,last_value(order_created_at) over (order by order_created_at) as last_order_date
    ,first_value(num_of_products) over (order by order_created_at) as first_order_date
    ,last_value(num_of_products) over (order by order_created_at) as last_order_date
FROM tableb
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by true) = 1
```

Lastly we can use another CTE to tweak the tableb and find the first and last order per customer, and then filter the non-first/last out with a QUALIFY (this is useful if you have thousands of customers with millions of orders, to make the target of the JOIN smaller). Then join on the first row number and last row number:

```
WITH tablea(customer_id,first_order_date, last_order_date) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
    (123, '2017-04-06','2018-07-30'),
    (456, '2017-08-07','2018-07-24'),
    (789, '2018-03-13','2018-07-03')
), tableb(order_id, customer_id, order_created_at, num_of_products, num_of_x_products) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('abc',123,'2017-04-06',4,2),
    ('xyz',123,'2018-07-30',5,3),
    ('def',456,'2017-08-07',6,6),
    ('lmn',456,'2018-07-24',4,1),
    ('ghi',789,'2018-03-13',6,5),
    ('pqr',789,'2018-07-03',3,3)
), tweaked_tableb AS (
    SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by customer_id order by order_created_at ASC) as first_rn,
         ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by customer_id order by order_created_at DESC) as last_rn
    FROM tableb
    QUALIFY first_rn = 1 OR last_rn = 1
)
SELECT a.customer_id
    ,a.first_order_date
    ,a.last_order_date
    ,fb.num_of_products
    ,lb.num_of_products
FROM tablea AS a
JOIN tweaked_tableb AS fb
    ON a.customer_id = fb.customer_id AND fb.first_rn = 1
JOIN tweaked_tableb AS lb
    ON a.customer_id = lb.customer_id AND lb.last_rn = 1
;
```